# Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK IOS gives records with system token null

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-ios

We have configured an app to connect a client app with Marketing Cloud through Marketing Cloud SDK.

Android Platform records are being registered correctly but IOS Platform records are being registered without system token.

All the other information is there: DeviceID, Platform, Platform Version...

Comment: Please open a support case.

Comment: Hi @BillMote, i opened a support case and the answer was 
"The sdk has no direct support from MC Suport as this is an open source system.[...] I have just tested the addition and registration of iOS contacts in my account and it works normally. I have passed all required fields in the code and my device got registered. I hope this makes sense."

Comment: Please have the person on your support case at-mention me.  They are 100% incorrect, or at least provide me with the case # here.

Comment: The case is #42173302. Thank you

Comment: That number does not produce any results in our systems.

Comment: It is closed because of that answer. I am going to create another one and mention you

Comment: The SDK is not open source and support should 100% be supporting it.  When they exhaust their knowledge they should be reaching out to my team for further help.

Comment: The new case number is 42243854, in 'Working' status

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea where you're getting those numbers from as they produce nothing in our system for me :). Please have the support person at-mention me on the case.